# Setup alerting policy for GCP Cloud Functions based on HTTP status codes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to setup Cloud Monitoring to alert me each time my Cloud Function responds with 4xx / 5xx HTTP status codes. Please let me know how to implement this from Cloud Console.

Comment: Unfortunately http-triggered cloud functions do not have a separate field for the status code of a certain execution. There are two ways around this issue: 1. You specify a filter status="error" in  an Alerting policy. This will be triggered by the complete http-error range 2. In case you want to filter for a specifc http-code you could create a Log-based Metric with a filter such as: textPayload:"finished with status code: 500"

Comment: I should add that the metric should be "Executions" for option 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Cloud Logging for this.

- Go to the Cloud Logging page and filter your logs
- Then select the part of the logs that you want (in my screen shot is the 200 HTTP response code), and click on "show matching entries"

[image]

- Now, in the query builder, you have the matching entry that you select
  [image]

You can change it, the value (400 instead of 200) the equality by > or <,... So, you can see in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries) how to build a Cloud Logging filter

- Then go to Action and click on create metrics

[image]

- Now create your metric and name it.

[image]

- Finally, click on the 3 dots on the right and select create an alert on this metric

[image]

- From there, follow the wizard. Name your condition, define your threshold and notification channels. *I think it's the easiest part (but if you need guidance, let me know)*

Comment: I can create the log query successfully but for some reason, it always returns 0 results. Note that this is for GCF. My log query is:

resource.type="cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name="cloud-fn-test"
resource.labels.region="us-central1"
httpRequest.status=200