# Creating alert policy from log based metrics doesn't show up any logs in the Alert page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, google-cloud-metrics

I have created a custom metric (query: resource.type=gae_app "protoPayload.methodName=google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion")from the Log Explorer and trying to create an alert policy for that. I don't find the resource_type "Log metrics" as referred in many documents/videos.
If I choose a resource.type=gae_app and refer the custom metric created in the alert configuration, it doesn't show up any logs in the created alert policy.

Comment: is the lastest steps of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092493/google-cloud-functions-monitor-http-status-codes/65097812#65097812) help you? If no, I don't really understand what you try to achieve and where you are struggled.

Comment: First of all I would recommend to check if the log based metric produces any data by itself without the alerting policy.After you check in Monitoring that the log based metric  is showing the data that you want you can and then create an alert policy with for it. See: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#alert-on-lbm